# Can't start a call when a button in a UITableViewCell is pressed

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton, call

Every cell in my tableview has a button. I want to call a number when the button is pressed. I have used calling from code before like this:

```
NSString *cifra1=@"tel://";
NSString *cifra=customer.tel;     
cifra1 = [cifra1 stringByAppendingString:cifra];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cifra1]];
```

If i put this code in method "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" everything works. But if i put it in `-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *) sender` nothing happens. I checked this method with NSLog and it responds to button clicks.

What is wrong?

EDIT: Strange, this works:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


NSString *cifra1=@"tel://";
NSString *cifra=@"123456789";
cifra1 = [cifra1 stringByAppendingString:cifra];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cifra1]];
```

}

and this doesnt, evethough the customer number is read correctly:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

Customer *c=[customerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *cifra1=@"tel://";
NSString *cifra=c.tel;
cifra1 = [cifra1 stringByAppendingString:cifra];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cifra1]];
```

}

Comment: How do you get the telephone number i.e. `customer.tel`. Does this vary over different rows? If so how do refer to it from the `-buttonPressed:` method.

Comment: Can you show the full code of didSelectRowAtIndexPath in order I can say what is wrong in (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *) sender

Comment: @Deepak: I logged the number from custoemr.tel when the button is pressed and everything is ok, i get the right number.

Comment: Can you post both the methods? It seems strange for it to work in one method and not the other.

Answer (score 0):

It's your buttonPressed called?

Try to add `NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);`

Try to use id instead of UIButton:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id) sender
```

Answer (score 0):

(IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *) sender

change it as (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id) sender

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
NSString *cifra = [[c.tel copy] autorelease];
```

I suspect you are using core data.

Comment: This doesnt help and i am not using core data. Only making string literal with NSString *cifra=@"123456789" works . I dont get it.

Comment: what is the value of `cifra1` prior to `openURL:`? Can you check with an `NSLog`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the target of the button with `addTarget:action:withObject:forControlEvents:`

Comment: buttonPressed is called successfully, the problem is not here.